# How to finfd the limit of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let  $(a_n)$ be a sequence defined by $a_1=1, a_2=2$ and $a_{n+2}=\frac{3}{4}a_n+\frac{1}{4}a_{n+1}$ for all $n\ge1$. How to prove this recursive sequence is convergent and find the limit?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the general term by solving $4x^2-x-3=0\implies x=1,-{3\over4}$.

So $a_n=A(-{3\over4})^n+B$ and sub in initial values you can find $a_n={16\over21}(-{3\over4})^n+{11\over7}$ hence it converges to $11\over 7$.